# Who did I just ping?

Tags: support, comments

My [slave mountain](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/103601/how-many-slaves-do-i-need-to-keep-my-mountain-palace-supplied?noredirect=1#comment312412_103601) question was commented on by two Tim B's; [Diamond Tim B](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/49/tim-b), and [Nova Tim B](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/44692/tim-b).

I replied to Diamond Tim B in a comment @TimB.

Which Tim B did I just ping? Both?

Comment: What did autocomplete say?

Comment: @dot_Sp0T It said TimB; which is technically neither of their names, since they both have a space. Both names are identical, as far as I can tell; there are also two James's on the site and I'm sure more. I'm just wondering how the ping mechanism works in this case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The one who posted most recently. See also: [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/352819):

> Matching is performed in reverse chronological order, so if five people named John are participating, @john will match the most recent John.

In your case [you have pinged diamond Tim](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5815/28789).

There doesn't seem to be a way to reply to someone who wrote a comment earlier and has the same username as someone who posted later - there is no way to ping not-diamond Tim right now, unless he decides to write another comment and thereby making the diamond Tim unavailable for pinging under your question.

---

After some tests in the chat with [AndyD273 pinging Secret and Secespitus at the same time by using "@Sec"](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/42601574#42601574) the mechanism seems to work differently in the chat. See also [Disable three-letter pings from chat to save Oliver, Olivier and Olive from Oli's pings](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234029/disable-three-letter-pings-from-chat-to-save-oliver-olivier-and-olive-from-oli)

Comment: I did autocomplete, so I must have pinged the correct TimB. Huzzah!

Comment: @kingledion I looked it up again because I was not entirely sure. I thought I have read somewhere that you can also choose the earlier poster, but apparently you can only ping the most recent one if the names are identical.

Comment: so I can do @king and kingledion will be pinged. That is sweet sweet knowledge!

Comment: Exactly @dot - the only thing needed is three characters after the "@"

Answer (score 11):

Me............................

Answer (score 3):

Not me.

We have to fix this. More accurately, *I* have to fix this, I'm the Johnny come lately. What do I need to do here? Is it as simple as changing my name in the profile? Will that muck up all the other references in answers that refer back to Tim B UnDiamond?

**Update**
Hopefully this solves the problem. :)

Comment: There's no real need to worry about it, although there is some potential for confusion. When I spotted the name overlap I looked at some of your answers and they were all good so I didn't mind being associated :D Renaming your profile as you've done will work, it won't mess up any actual links to anything, and the name is still similar enough that mentions by name should be clear enough.

Comment: I do like the update, I was confused for a while about when Tim B stopped being a moderator :)

Comment: Hi Tim, I did the same thing and thought 'cool', but time for me to leave the nest and stand on my own. :)

Comment: I would have opted for "Tim B₂" myself ;)

Comment: In Australia, that has a whole Bananas in Pyjamas connotation though. :)